# Creating a .jar file

Tags: java, user-interface, jar, creation

I'm creating a .jar file that has a GUI:

```
jar cmf mainClass patcherFull.jar pack
```

I get no errors with the creation command above, but then running the .jar file does nothing in Windows, and running it with java itself outputs:

```
java -jar patcherFull.jar
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: patcherFull
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: patcherFull
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: patcherFull. Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

This is my code structure:

```
public class patcherFull extends JPanel implements ActionListener, PropertyChangeListener
{

  private JProgressBar progressBar;
  private JButton startButton, closeButton;
  private JLabel status;
  private Task task;

    class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void done()
        {
        }
    }

    public patcherFull()
    {
  }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
    }

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
    {
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
          }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my mainClass manifest file (with a new line at the end):

```
Main-Class: patcherFull
```

Is there something wrong within my code structure? And as an FYI, the "pack" folder has the 3 generated .class files, 2 dependencies (a jpg and an exe) and then the "patcherFull.java" file.

Here is some more info on what's inside the .jar:

```
$ jar tf patcherFull.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
pack/
pack/banner.jpg
pack/patcherFull$1.class
pack/patcherFull$Task.class
pack/patcherFull.class
pack/patcherFull.java
pack/wget.exe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main class should be `pack.patcherFull`, not `patcherFull`, to conform to your structure in the jar file.

Also note that convention dictates that it should be `pack.PatcherFull`.

Comment: So you're meaning changing my manifest file to "Main-Class: pack.patcherFull"? I get an error when I do that.

Comment: stand inside `pack` when you create the jar